# Annotations in XStream without known class type

Tags: java, generics, serialization, xml-serialization, xstream

I have following, problem with XStream: when I try to read the annotations I need to use following sentence:

```
xstream.processAnnotations(DataClass .class);
```

which defines explicitly the class I'm going to serialize. But in my code:

```
public class Tester {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataClass data = new DataClass();
        data.familyName = "Pil";
        data.firstName = "Paco";
        data.ID = 33;
        data.properties.put("one", "1");
        data.properties.put("two", "2");
        data.properties.put("three", "3");

        String xml = getXmlString(data);
        System.out.println(xml);
    }

    public static  String getXmlString(Object data) {
        String ret = "";
        final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
        xstream.processAnnotations(Object.class);
        xstream.marshal(data, new PrettyPrintWriter(stringWriter));

        ret = stringWriter.toString();

        return ret;
    }
}
```

where the dataClass is:

```
@XStreamAlias("data")
public class DataClass {
    public Integer ID = 0;
    public String firstName = "";
    public String familyName = "";
    public Map<String, String> properties = null;

    public DataClass(){
        properties = new HashMap<String,String>();
    }
}
```

I would like to have something like that:

```
public static  <T> String getXmlString(T data) {
        String ret = "";
        final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
        xstream.processAnnotations(T.class);
        xstream.marshal(data, new PrettyPrintWriter(stringWriter));

        ret = stringWriter.toString();

        return ret;
    }
```

but it doesn't work.

Do anyone know if it is possible what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should enabled "[Auto-detect Annotations](http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html#AutoDetect)" mode:

```
public static <T> String getXmlString(T data) {
    final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

    XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xstream.autodetectAnnotations(true);
    xstream.marshal(data, new PrettyPrintWriter(stringWriter));

    return stringWriter.toString();
}
```

Please, read "[Auto-detect Annotations](http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html#AutoDetect)" paragraph. You can find in it all information about problems which are linked with this solution. Such as: Chicken-and-egg problem, Concurrency, Exceptions and Performance.

Result:

```
<data>
  <ID>33</ID>
  <firstName>Paco</firstName>
  <familyName>Pil</familyName>
  <properties>
    <entry>
      <string>two</string>
      <string>2</string>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <string>one</string>
      <string>1</string>
    </entry>
    <entry>
      <string>three</string>
      <string>3</string>
    </entry>
  </properties>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you creat an `init()` method that initializes your xstream object. Let your xstream object have class scope. I have never had a reason to create more than one xstream object within a project, so I usually handle it this way. You could even make it a static field. Place all of your annotation processing methods within `init()` and explicitly register every class you expect to serialize.

Comment: My xstream object cannot have class scope because I'm using static methods. I 'm doing a "utilities" class that can be used in the rest of the project. But your comment gave me one idea :)

Comment: I handled this the same exact way - all of my File access code consisted of static methods. Make xstream static and call a static init() method BEFORE calling any of the other static methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
if(data != null) xstream.processAnnotations(data.getClass());
```

to access the direct class of the `data` object, but as Thorn suggests it's probably better to declare a single `XStream` instance that knows about all the classes you will be serializing.

Comment: Thanks! this is fine! I didn't knew about this getClass() method!

Comment: I cannot declare the single XStream method as my system should be able to serialize classes not generated by me.

Comment: @Rafa in that case [mykhaylo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14896680/592139) is probably the better way to go.  Using `autodetectAnnotations` works fine for serializing, but you need to call `processAnnotations` for each relevant class explicitly before you can _de_-serialize anything.

Comment: this is true, I think I should award mykhaylo with the "resolved" tick.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found one solution, it may be not the best, but as I need to really be VERY flexible, it the solution that best fit my needs:

```
public static  <T> String getXmlString(T data, Class<?> dataClass) {
        String ret = "";
        final StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();

        XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
        xstream.processAnnotations(dataClass);
        xstream.marshal(data, new PrettyPrintWriter(stringWriter));

        ret = stringWriter.toString();

        return ret;
    }
```

I will be very happy if someone find somethig better. I'm quite new to Java and probably I'm not using all the cool features of this language.

Comment: If you go this route you could make the signature `public static  <T> String getXmlString(T data, Class<T> dataClass)` to get the compiler to check that `data` really is an instance of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not directly related to this question but if you use Spring XStreamMarshaller, you need to turn on the detection of XStream annotations as follow:

```
    <bean id="xStreamMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
       <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```